# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (bootstrap.js:1) (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, bootstrap-5

I'm building a Web application using ASP.NET. But I have encountered a ridiculous error and don't know how to fix it.

I have updated my project's bootstrap version to 5.3.1 from 3.4.1 from NuGet. After that, my website still loaded, but had something wrong. My bootstrap still appeared, but in chrome Dev Tool, an error occurred `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (bootstrap.js:1)`.

Here is my project configure, including `BundleConfig.js`, `_Layout.cshtml`:

*BundleConfig.js*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace myproject
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            ...

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));


            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                "~/Content/Site.css"));

        }
    }
}
```

*_layout.cshtml*

```
...
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
...
```

I have checked and my bootstrap.js still appears under my Scripts folder.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: It should have been `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")` in _layout.cshtml

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but you can fix it by replacing *ScriptBundle* with *Bundle* in `BundleConfig.cs`

```
...
bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));
...
```